# embed ipython notebook in sphinx document

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-sphinx

I am writing the API document for my own project. 
And I found that this cool [documentation](http://yt-project.org/doc/quickstart/data_objects_and_time_series.html) (yt project) uses ipython notebook directly to give example. When I looked into their documentation repo on bitbucket, one relevant rst seemed quite simple as:

```
.. notebook:: An_example_notebook.ipynb
```

But, of course, it didn't work for me.  I am not sure if the "notebook" is an intrinsic block type or not. Maybe the 'notebook' block requires an external package. Actually, I got zero result when I searched for "notebook" in the sphinx documentation.

If I can use my notebooks directly (without converting) to give examples, that will make life much easier. 
But I can't figure out how I can achieve that.

Comment: something like that: http://nbsphinx.readthedocs.io/en/0.2.8/ ?

Comment: They are using https://github.com/ngoldbaum/RunNotebook

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`nbsphinx` is a Sphinx extension that provides a source parser for `*.ipynb` files.

To Install nbsphinx:

```
pip install nbsphinx --user
```

Edit your `conf.py` and add `'nbsphinx'` to extensions.

Edit your `index.rst` and add the names of your `*.ipynb` files to the `toctree`.

Follow This [Link](http://nbsphinx.readthedocs.io/en/0.2.8/rst.html) after the above thing you do

Run Sphinx!

Comment: thank you, may you provide a sample of how to refer the notebook? so far I see an only empty page on my side... :/

Answer (score 0):

Another opinion is to use `myst-nb` instead of `nbsphinx`. Unfortunately, `nbsphinx` requires `pandoc` installation. In addition, `nbsphinx` requires to have a title to your notebooks with hyphens (-) instead of spaces. While `myst-nb` requires only a title and works without issues

1. Install `myst-nb`: `pip install myst-nb`
2. Add `"myst_nb"` to extensions in `conf.py` file to read both `md` files and `ipynb` files. Note that you need to remove `"myst_parser"` (which reads only `md` files) from the extensions to avoid this error: `Config value 'myst_commonmark_only' already present`.
3. Now include your notebook files in `toctree` directive. Note that you do not have to provide the extension with the file name since it works either way.

More information: [myst-nb.readthedocs](https://myst-nb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html)